# Hive query error with Json

Tags: java, json, apache, hadoop, hive

I'm creating a table using the twitter cloudera example, while I've successfully created the table and get the data, I'm encountering a problem.

I can perform a `select * from tweets;` and returned the data, but when I go more deeper like a `count(*)` I'm receiving an error.

Here's the table created:

> ADD JAR
>   /cdh-twitter-example/hive-serdes/target/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
>   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (    id BIGINT,    created_at STRING,
>   source STRING,    favorited BOOLEAN,    retweet_count INT,
>   retweeted_status STRUCT<
>         text:STRING,
>         user:STRUCT>,    entities STRUCT<
>         urls:ARRAY>,
>         user_mentions:ARRAY>,
>         hashtags:ARRAY>>,    text STRING,    user STRUCT<
>         screen_name:STRING,
>         name:STRING,
>         friends_count:INT,
>         followers_count:INT,
>         statuses_count:INT,
>         verified:BOOLEAN,
>         utc_offset:INT,
>         time_zone:STRING>,    in_reply_to_screen_name STRING ) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' LOCATION
>   '/user/flume/tweets';

Here's the error and stack trace:

> hive> select count(*) from tweets; Total MapReduce jobs = 1 Launching
>   Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1 In
>   order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):   set
>   hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer= In order to limit the
>   maximum number of reducers:   set hive.exec.reducers.max= In
>   order to set a constant number of reducers:   set
>   mapred.reduce.tasks= Starting Job = job_1402410026954_0004,
>   Tracking URL =
>   http://bigdatalite.localdomain:8088/proxy/application_1402410026954_0004/
>   Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill
>   job_1402410026954_0004 Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of
>   mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1 2014-06-10 13:07:28,078 Stage-1 map
>   = 0%,  reduce = 0% 2014-06-10 13:07:39,983 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0% 2014-06-10 13:07:41,071 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0% 2014-06-10 13:08:18,527 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100% Ended Job =
>   job_1402410026954_0004 with errors Error during job, obtaining
>   debugging information... Examining task ID:
>   task_1402410026954_0004_m_000000 (and more) from job
>   job_1402410026954_0004
>
> Task with the most failures(4): 
>   ----- Task ID:   task_1402410026954_0004_m_000000
>
> tipid=task_1402410026954_0004_m_000000
>   ----- Diagnostic Messages for this Task: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163) Caused
>   by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in
>   configuring object    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
>     ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
>     ... 17 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator
>   initialization failed     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:134)
>     ... 22 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe not found   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:314)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:333)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:103)
>     ... 22 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe not found   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1801)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:284)
>     ... 24 more
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
>   Job 0: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL Total
>   MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which CDH version are you running?

Comment: Hello, I'm using CDH 5

Comment: Try copying the hive-serdes jar into `/usr/lib/hive/lib`

Comment: I've made a copy, restarted the hive services but the error persists, here how its looks like on the $HIVE_HOME/lib: lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   32 Apr 25 16:53 zookeeper.jar -> /usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper.jar
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   40 Apr 25 16:56 mysql-connector-java.jar -> /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 231K Jun 10 13:06 hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: What if you copy the jar into the same folder on all nodes?

Comment: Working on a dev environment right now before go prod, only 1 node.

Comment: Ok, you might have to put it in the hadoop lib folder as well.  This seems strange though

Comment: Okay... copy into /usr/lib/hadoop/lib worked! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copying the required library into the hadoop lib folder too, solves the issue.